# I'm not a king - What am I?

Tags: riddle, limerick

> I'm not a king or a royal
>   My hard job is fraught with toil
>   If I'm given a crown
>   You'll surely want to frown
>   Even more so when I'm foiled

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kind of a stretch, but are you a...

> tooth?

I'm not a king or a royal
My hard job is fraught with toil

> Being a tooth is hard work.

If I'm given a crown
You will want to frown

> Having a crown put on a tooth can be painful and unpleasant.

Even more so when I'm foiled

> Having aluminum foil in your mouth can be unpleasant as well [due to the voltaic effect it produces](https://science.howstuffworks.com/question564.htm).

Comment: Yes, you got it! Nice work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> A game of checkers / draughts

---

I'm not a king or a royal

> All pieces start of as "regular" pieces

My hard job is fraught with toil

> The job of each piece is to capture other pieces

If I'm given a crown
You will want to frown

> Once a piece reaches the other side of the board it can be "crowned" or "kinged" allowing it to move backwards

Even more so when I'm foiled

> But if it was one of your "kings" that was foiled / captured, you won't be as happy.